# Setting ALAsset name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation

- Per the AVCam sample, when browsing the photo album, the names given to the assets are of the IMG_* notation, I would like to change the name of the Asset to something meaningful, is it possible to set the name of the asset to anything other than 'IMG_*' ? how ?
- Is there any way to preserve free-text metadata with ALAsset objects ?

  Any help will be appreciated.